# What is the correct index on a large dataset with group by?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, index-tuning

I've been managing this very large data set for mlb data in mysql for awhile and am trying to rework the indexes to increase efficiency.

I have several instances I need to manage where I need to sort by several ranges and also return results grouped by the player.

As an example:

```
SELECT  `pitcher`
    FROM  `pitch_stats`
    WHERE  `game_year`='2022'
      and  `release_speed` < '82'
    group by  `pitcher`;
```

Obviously the index should include game year first, but after that is it more efficient to index by release speed (the next search variable) or by pitcher? Thus requiring a full search but no sorting once the results are flagged.

Is there another option that I'm missing which would be more efficient? Some of these queries can take 10+ seconds which seems excessive.

Comment: *Obviously the index should include game year first, but after that is it more efficient to index by release speed (the next search variable) or by pitcher?* Why not trying and see which one is faster ? explain will show you better

Answer (score 0):

What you need are two things

First, create an index with the three columns in this order

```
ALTER TABLE pitch_stats
ADD INDEX gy_pit_rs_index (game_year,pitcher,release_speed);
```

Second, rewrite the query to see every release_speed for the pitcher in that year and the average

```
SELECT pitcher
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(release_speed) all_release_speeds
    ,COUNT(release_speed) count_release_speeds
    ,AVG(release_speed) average_release_speed
FROM `pitch_stats`
WHERE `game_year`='2022'
and `release_speed` < '82'
group by `pitcher`;
```

Comment: Why the added aggregates to the `SELECT` clause?...perhaps something OP said in a comment no longer around?

Comment: @J.D. just some added info in case it is useful

Comment: Thanks for the response @RolandoMySQLDBA For clarification, the second part of your post is just an example as to how you could do more with the query right?  It is not necessary for a quicker response with the results?

Answer (score 0):

For *that* query...

1. `=` parts of `WHERE` -- `game_year`
2. one "range" part of `WHERE` -- `release speed.  Now` (game_year, release_speed, ...)` fully covers the filtering.
3. [optional] add all other columns being used anywhere in the query -- This makes the inde "covering".  `EXPLAIN` will say `"Using index" to indicate this.

So:

```
INDEX(game_year, release_speed, pitcher)
```

More:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

For Rolando's *revised* query, his different index may be better.